# filter a list for anything that contains any portion of any item from other list

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I'd like to shorten this function:

```
def get_filenames(path, banned_files=() ):
    file_list = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        BANNED_FILES = banned_files
        for f in files:
            for string in BANNED_FILES:
                if string in f:
                    continue
            path = os.path.join(root, f)
            file_list.append(path)
    return file_list
```

used as such:

```
filenames = get_filenames(CLIENT_TESTS_PATH, banned_files=['__init__.py', '.pyc', 'accounts.py, otherfile.py'])
```

such that whatever files from `CLIENT_TESTS_PATH` don't have any of the banned files within them. I can't just check if the filepath is in the banned files with list comprehension since I care if any of the banned files can be found anywhere within the client files. How can I shorten this with a filter, list comprehension, and or lambda efficiently? I only want the files in that dir, not dirs below it. 
Thank you

For

```
def get_files(path, banned_files=[]):
    return [os.path.join(root, fname) for root, _, fnames in os.path.walk(path) for fname in fnames \
                if not any(bad_fname in fname for bad_fname in banned_files)]
```

I get

```
In [2]: CLIENT_TESTS_PATH = "/home/cchilders/work_projects/webapi"    

In [3]: get_files(CLIENT_TESTS_PATH)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3c5a75968d68> in <module>()
----> 1 get_files(CLIENT_TESTS_PATH)

/home/cchilders/scripts/my_scripting_library/sysadmin.py in get_files(path, banned_files)
     15 
     16 def get_files(path, banned_files=[]):
---> 17     return [os.path.join(root, fname) for root, _, fnames in os.path.walk(path) for fname in fnames \
     18                 if not any(bad_fname in fname for bad_fname in banned_files)]
     19 

TypeError: walk() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Don't use mutable default arguments - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: in his code, that's not an issue, as the OP does not mutate the argument, and does not try to return it.

Comment: @zmo -- You're right.  There is no danger here.  But it's still not a good habit.  A tuple would work just as well for the default.

Comment: ya, it just so rarely causes an issue I do overlook the tuple aspect

Comment: You probably want to use `os.walk()` instead of (deprecated) `os.path.walk()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
banned_files=['__init__.py', '.pyc', 'accounts.py', 'otherfile.py']
file_list = ["""Some list of files here"""] 
new_list = {file_name for file_name in file_list for bf in banned_files if bf not in file_name}
```

This will filter out anything that has these strings in the file name at all. That means something like `"my_accounts.py.txt"` would be blocked. It might be better to separate them. For example:

```
banned_files=['__init__.py', 'accounts.py', 'otherfile.py']
banned_extensions = ['.pyc']
new_list = {file_name for file_name in file_list for ext in banned_extensions if file_name not in banned_files and not file_name.endswith(ext)}
```

Editing to include os.walk... one second.

Comment: I like the golfing but I don't understand it. there's 3 fors lol can we break it down

Comment: @codyc4321 Yes, this is a set comprehension. Comprehensions can get very messy as they increase in constraints. However, it would actually be faster to apply the banned files and extensions separately.

Comment: actually this wasn't what I was thinking but seems best

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension:

```
def get_filenames(path, banned_files=()):
    return [os.path.join(root, f) for root,_,files in os.walk(path) for f in files]
```

That does the same thing as the code that you *posted*, but it probably doesn't do what you want.  Your `for string in BANNED_FILES:` loop is completely useless because all that it does is continue, but `continue` works only in the current loop; it does not affect the `for f in files:` loop, so that inner loop does absolutely nothing except waste processing time.  To do what I think you *want*, do this:

```
def get_filenames(path, banned_files=()):
    return [os.path.join(root, f) 
            for root,_,files in os.walk(path)
                for f in files
                    if not any(string in f for string in banned_files)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[os.path.join(root, fname) for root, _, fnames in os.path.walk(path) for fname in fnames \
    if not any(bad_fname in fname for bad_fname in banned)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_filenames(path, banned_files=()):
    file_list = [os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk(path)
                 for f in files if all(s not in f for s in banned_files)]
    return file_list
```

Comment: this goes beyond that current dir

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is IMHO the clearest way :

```
[os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk(path) \
for f in files  if all([bf not in f for bf in banned_files])]
```

Don't forget the brackets in the all() :

```
In [7]: [f for f in ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']   if all([bf not in f \
for bf in ['a','e','z']])]
Out[7]: ['ghi', 'jkl']

In [8]: [f for f in ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']   if all(bf not in f \
for bf in ['a','e','z'])]
Out[8]: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
def get_filenames(path, banned_files=[]):
    banned = '|'.join(banned_files)
    return [os.path.join(root, f)
            for root, _, files in os.walk(path)
            for f in files
            if f not in banned]
```

Explanation:

`|` can't be used in filenames, so we can use it as a delimiter for the string containing all banned files. Checking found file names against single string is much faster.